# ssh to aws permission denied (public key) using ubuntu@ why is it failing?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I can't seem to use SSH to connect to AWS although I don't usually have any problems with github or heroku. The debug is below, I've tried @ubuntu and @ec2-user (it should be @ubuntu), I've also tried creating a config file in .ssh (on windows) and adding 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes' as that seemed to fix it on another thread, but no luck. I've modified the permissions of the.pem file to 400. I don't understand why it says it all sounds positive but then fails, if I could get a better idea of what the error is I might be able to find a solution. Any help very much appreciated!

```
$ ssh -v -i futurebot2.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-218-75-37.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/Mark/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-218-75-37.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.218.75.37] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file futurebot2.pem type -1
debug1: identity file futurebot2.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA f2:cd:94:4d:a1:9a:b5:67:cb:f7:91:d7:ef:4d:a4:3d
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-218-75-37.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Mark/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: futurebot2.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons why this might happen.

1. User does not exist, this might be due to connecting with the wrong user or an instance that is not your own (wrong ip address)
2. The user does not have your key in its authorized keys file. In AWS, the key you select at launch is added to your instance, but if you want to use other keys, you need to add them to your `authorized_keys` file manually.

Comment: Got, thank you. I'd set it up with one pair, created another as it didn't seem to work but it was still using the old pair. Setting up a new instance with the new pair got it working. Thanks very much!