# AWS prompts for password even though I have a key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to log into ASW after setting it up for the first time. I have been around the forums but cannot find someone with the same problem. Basically after I SSH in with my keypair files I get hit with a password request. After I do this:

```
chmod 400 x.pem   
ssh -i x.pem ubuntu@ec2-52-25-41-126.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

The forums recommend editing my sshd config file and setting:
    PasswordAuthentication yes

However how can I get to my sshd file I cannot get in in the first place?

Also... I logged into the AWS GUI but cannot find anywhere to modify this password.

So...would anyone know

1) how to modify SSHD_Config when I cannot log in via ssh
2) what the default password might be?

Thanks for our hep Community.

Comment: What OS/AMI are you logging into? Please add `-v` to the ssh command and paste that output. (edit your question, don't put it in as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the AWS system, and your actual instance are two seperate systems. They don't talk to each other (This is for a very good reason once you understand the system design).

If you want to change your instance authentication, you need to do so from within the instance. AWS does not have access to do this for you.

If you are having issues connecting to your instance via SSH, you need to post information about what error you are getting.

Its not recommended that you use password authentication, its generally less secure than using a private key.

Comment: Hi DataSage. Unfortunately I am not getting any Error that might help. As per my description I am using and keypair BUT I am still hitting a password after this point. I see many replies giving the advice you just gave but my situation isnt in that category. Somehow, while using a keypair, I am still asked for a password. I cannot actually login to change pass auth... so im kind of goosed at this point.

Comment: If it asks for a password, that means key auth has failed. This may be due to a bad key, or incorrect user name.

Comment: Hi. I have actually graduated to a new problem (timing out). But I just wanted to finish off the topic to say that I got by this issue by discovering (on stackoverflow) that its important to use the original keypair created with your instance. if you delete it and create a new one you would have to manually add it. I wasted a few hours on this missunderstanding. here is the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286782/ssh-to-aws-permission-denied-public-key-using-ubuntu-why-is-it-failing

Comment: If you are timing out, you are either connecting to the wrong IP, or you are being filtered by a firewall (which could be a local network, security group or software firewall on the instance)